# How to start a command on the second display at a particular position

Tags: command-line, multiple-monitors

I have a dual screen setup in Windows XP. I have several log file traces that I want to start up and have them positioned in a particular layout on the second screen. Is there a tool that allows me to start a command shell in a certain location? Or a tool that can be run from the command line to reposition a window that I can run in batch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to start a program at a fixed position in a batch file using [**CMDOW**](http://www.commandline.co.uk/cmdow/).

> Cmdow is a Win32 commandline utility
>   for NT4/2000/XP/2003 that allows
>   windows to be listed, moved, resized,
>   renamed, hidden/unhidden,
>   disabled/enabled, minimized,
>   maximized, restored,
>   activated/inactivated, closed, killed
>   and more.

Check the /MOV option:

> /MOV  Moves the specified window. The
>   left and top arguments specify the new
>   position of the left top corner of the
>   window. For level one windows this
>   relative to the desktop, and for child
>   windows this is relative to its parent
>   window. Level one windows can be moved
>   off the screen using negative coords
>   or coords greater than the desktop
>   size. You should not move a minimized
>   or maximized window without first
>   restoring it..

Comment: Looks like it would do the trick, but my company antivirus is blocking it. :(

Comment: They mention that on their website: "Some anti-virus software vendors now classify cmdow.exe as a hacking tool because it can hide windows. A hacking tool is NOT a virus."

Comment: I know that, but I work for corporation that works on policies.